# i want dfa that accept string of{a,b,c} that starting with a and ending with c and have even no. of b

Tags: finite-automata, dfa, nfa

i have done below dfa for this...but it's not right...please help me...valid strings are abbc,aabbcc,aabbbbc,abbcccc.
and invalid strings are abca,abc,abbcb,babbc.please help me.i have done this.

```
<?php
 include "config.php";
 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                    include('PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
                    $userName=$_REQUEST['username'];
                    $userEmail=$_REQUEST['mail'];
                    $userPhone=$_REQUEST['mobile'];
                    $subject=$_REQUEST['sub'];
                    $userMsg=$_REQUEST['msg'];
//i have image of DFA. but, i don't have 10 reputation so,i can't upload it...
?>
```

stackoverflow not accepting my question so i put my explanation in php.please avoid php tag.
please help me...i really stuck with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this dfa will work.........[image]